# How do I make a function call with jquery get?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I am trying to authenticate a user using jquery to a call back function on the server code behind. Here is what i have done so far :

```
$.get('Authenticate.aspx', function (data){
            var auth = data.toString();

});
```

The Authenticate.aspx code behind looks like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("hello");
    }
```

how do i go about returning say a boolean value to the client side variable ?
what is the best way to do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ASP.NET Web Forms? Why not use MVC?

MVC allows you to return JsonResult (instead of ActionResult). It will serialize the return data that you can use in javascript.

Check out http://shashankshetty.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/using-jsonresult-with-jquery-in-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: i am half through finishing this now , how can i do this in asp.net web forms ?

Answer (score 0):

In the page load event (sorry, its in vb):

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
If *check authenticated* Then
    Response.Write(New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(New With {.success = True}))
Else
    Response.Write(New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(New With {.success = False}))
End If
```

This shouldn't be difficult to convert to c#, and obviously you can clean it up with using statements.

Your jquery function will also need to change to something like:

```
var auth = data.success();
```